# How to add a new tax line in invoice odoo v11

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-11

i'm using odoo 11 and i have created a custom module to add a new tax line in invoice.I notice that this code is functional in odoo 9 but it return nothing in odoo 11 and it doesn't shows error. Any idea and help please to resolve this probleme

account_invoice.py

```
from odoo import models, fields, osv

class fiscal_stamp(models.Model):
_inherit = "res.company"
description = fields.Many2one('account.account' , string='Libellé Taxe')
montant = fields.Float(string='Montant')

class account_invoice(osv.osv):
_name = "account.invoice"
_inherit = "account.invoice"

def create(self, cr, uid, values, context=None):
    invoice_id = super(account_invoicing, self).create(cr, uid, values, context)

    res_company = self.pool.get('res.company')

    stamp_account = res_company.browse(cr, uid, values.get('company_id')).description.id
    tax_value = res_company.browse(cr, uid, values.get('company_id')).montant

    if stamp_account:
        account_invoice_tax = self.pool.get('account.invoice.tax')

        tax_line_values = {'base': 0,
                           'amount': tax_value,
                           'name': 'Timbre',
                           'account_id': stamp_account,
                           'invoice_id': invoice_id
                           }

        account_invoice_tax.create(cr, uid, tax_line_values)

    return invoice_id
```

Comment: By default tax line is there when invoice is created from sale order. Do you want external access for creation of tax line ?

Comment: i want to add to each invoice a specific tax called stamp tax"